# AVPlayer - play network video with separate audio URL without downloading the files first

Tags: ios, swift, video, tvos

I'm currently trying to play a video using `AVPlayer` that has separate sources for video and audio, so I combine them into a single `AVPlayerItem` as below:

```
let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL)
let audioAsset = AVURLAsset(url: audioURL)
let duration = videoAsset.duration
let composition = AVMutableComposition()

let videoTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
try? videoTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: kCMTimeZero, duration: duration), of: videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0], at: kCMTimeZero)

let audioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
try? audioTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: kCMTimeZero, duration: duration), of: audioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio)[0], at: kCMTimeZero)

let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: composition)
```

However the problem is that this code **fetches the entire source** of the video and audio over the network before it completes. Either calling 'videoAsset.duration' or `videoTrack.insertTimeRange` triggers this network request.

Is there a way to use `AVPlayer` to play these separate video and audio URLs together (MP4 video and AAC audio) without having to download the entire file first?

I've noticed that on my Mac, Quicktime Player also fetches the source file before it begins playback. However using something like VLC or IINA doesn't and playback can start immediately.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find out how to fix this? I think using loadValuesAsynchronously might work, but I haven't had time to try that yet.

Comment: @gallileo See my answer below for what I did instead. I didn't look into  `loadValuesAsynchronously` as it seems that helps with loading assets without blocking the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a way to use `AVPlayer` to achieve this. Instead I used [VLCKit](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/VLCKit) which supports playback slaves from different sources.

Comment: Any chance you can provide me with a small gist on how you served both the audio and video stream URL to VLCKit? I'm working on something similar and would like to fetch some 1080p / 720p YT videos.

Comment: In your `VLCMediaPlayer` instance, call `addPlaybackSlave`. `player.addPlaybackSlave(audioURL, type: .audio, enforce: true)`

Answer (score 2):

This is because of MP4 format. You should consider using another format that is more stable for streaming.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my stream, but YouTube's DASH streaming format that has separate video and audio.